# How can I Resync a fork from original

Tags: git, merge, github, forking

I just forked a project in Github. I made modifications and sent a pull request. The owner merged my fork with the main project and after that he made some modifications. So for now my fork is not updated with the main project. I miss the modifications he made after merging my pull request.
How can I update my fork with the Main project? Is there a way to do that in the web interface?

Thanks

Comment: I write a simple instruction. check out at here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58140/63016

Comment: There's now an official doc which is well done: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By design, forking a project creates a separate repo that is not updated when the original repo changes. However, `git` makes it pretty easy to update manually.

You need the help of a 3rd repository (your local copy suffices). There are 3 repos:

- "Upstream": The upstream project's repository on Github.
- "Origin": Your fork's repository on Github
- "Local": Your local repository on your computer. I will assume you created it by cloning Fork using `git clone git@github.com:your-username/projectname.git`, and that everyone is using branch `master`.

Assuming currently "Origin" and "Local" are in the same state, and "Upstream" is ahead by 1 or more commits (the merge and any subsequent changes).

First add the upstream project as a [Git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream-username/projectname.git
```

Then pull (meaning *fetch* and then *merge* automatically) the changes from the remote's `master` branch into your local repository's current (`master`) branch:

```
git pull upstream master
```

Now your local repository is in sync with `upstream`. Finally, push your local repo to your Github fork:

```
git push origin master
```

Now everything is in sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's a shame that this may not be possible to make that in the web interface..

Comment: This is indeed possible on the web interface: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31010/10390

Comment: Yeehaw! I had been tearing my hair out trying to find this explicit info. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: ... but please take also a look at the answer's comments, proving that Resync via web is not the best option as it pollutes repository

Comment: what do you do when it says "already up to date" after the pull, but it is obviously not? (there are files I changed all in one subdirectory, and I should have no differences in any other file, but I do)

Comment: what if the `main` branch is protected?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a remote (see [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote)) and pull from that new remote.

```
git remote add mainProject https://github.com/user/mainProject
git pull mainProject master
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508039/5956071) to complement the original answer as that only deals with syncing one branch (master). In addition, if the branch has been created on the upstream since your fork, it is a little more involved to create it on your fork.

The short answer is, to update your fork with every branch on the upstream repository, execute this command.

```
for branch in $(git ls-remote --heads upstream|sed 's#^.*refs/heads/##'); do git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/$branch:refs/heads/$branch; done
```

What this does not do is remove any branches from your fork that have been deleted from the upstream. There is no way to automate that especially if you have created branches on your fork.